# Stop the execution of a cancelled request in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am creating an application which makes a lot of HTTP requests to another server and it may take up to 1 minute to complete one of such requests. Some of the users cancel the request, however my app still executes the cancelled requests.

Here is my code :

```
var app = express();
app.get('/something', function (req, res) {
    function timeout(i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // lets assume there is a http request.
            console.log(i);
            timeout(++i);
        }, 100);
    }
    req.connection.on('close', function () {
        console.log('I should do something');
    });
    timeout(1);
});
app.listen(5000);
```

Basically, What I want is stop console.log(i) calls after client closes connection. Also, If possible the client omit "close-{id}" event and when backend recevies close-{id} event, it terminates {id} request.

Note : I used setTimeout to show callback mechanizim. It is not the real code.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation, "http.request() returns an instance of the http.ClientRequest class."  You could call the abort() method of the returned object. (Warning, untested code).

```
var http = require('http'); // This needs to go at the top of the file.

app.get('/something', function (req, res) {
    var remote_request = http.request("www.something.com", function(data){
                             res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
                             res.end(data);
                         });
    req.on("close", function() {
        remote_request.abort();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I think there is a misunderstanding. When client closes connection, I want to quit node application in order to not start any further requests to something.com not want to abort a particular request.

Comment: @onum Do you really want to quit your entire node application if a user cancels the request?

Comment: not entire application, only for this request to prevent new callback calls.

Comment: @onum That is exactly what my code is supposed to achieve. I'm not sure why you have a setTimeout function in your request handler.  What is that for?  You're making an http request 10 times per second, or is it to simulate a long request?

Comment: yes it is a simulate for multiple request. In one call, I have to execute 200 requests. So you can thinks as a for loop that itaretes to 200, and there is a http request and callback every loop. Immediately, there will be 200 requests

Comment: I would need to see more of your finished idea before commenting further.  That's a LOT of requests per client connection.  Are you assembling a response to the client based on responses from all those requests?  I guess in your loop you could keep an array of references to each http.request object and then loop through it and call the abort method for each one.

Comment: Yes I am assembling a lot of API calls for one request. Keeping references in an array might be solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assign your `setTimeout` to a var, and then use `clearTimeout` in the `close` handler. If might take some clever restructuring based on your method structure but something like:

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout(...)
...
req.connection.on('close', function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```